# How to take multiple inputs of integer using scanner and to use for same equation in java to produce different output?

Tags: java

**Code::**

```
package practice;

import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

public class Practice{

public static void main(String []argh){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int s2 = 0,s1=0, res = 0,a=0,b=0,n=0;

         a = in.nextInt();
        b = in.nextInt();
       n = in.nextInt();


    if(a>=0 && b<=50){
    } 


    if (n>=1 && n<=15){
        for(int j=0;j<=n-1;j++){
            int c= (int)Math.pow(2,j);

        s1 =   c * (b);
       s2 = s1+s2;
       res = a+s2;
            System.out.print(res + " ");
    }   }
        }
   //in.close();
}
//}
```

============================================================================

> Input:
>
> 0
>
> 2
>
> 10
>
> Output:
>
> 2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046

=======================

I want to ask user how many queries/how many inputs and has to accept the integer values and process output.

> Sample Input
>
> 2
>
> 0 2 10
>
> 5 3 5
>
> Sample Output
>
> 2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046
>
> 8 14 26 50 98

Comment: use google and split your question in smaller parts like: ask user for input multiple times etc

Comment: what is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: Meaningful variable names go a long way too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading 3 integers separately, scanner can read a line with 3 numbers separated by spaces and `split` the string to populate 3 meaning-named integer variable and go from there.